# Are there separate call tree depths for recursive and non-recursive calls?

Tags: python, recursion

As we all know, if you have a function like this:

```
def foo():
    foo()
```

The function will call itself 1000 times and then you get a `RecursionError` exception.

But what if you had a thousand and one *different* functions that call each other?  i.e. `a()` calls `b()` calls `c()` and so on.

Would you get any sort of error at the 1001st call?  The call stack depth would be the same as in the recursive case, even though there isn't any actual recursion.

Comment: I would expect the same error. You're stacking call frames in both cases. The difference in the recursive case is the frames are associated with calls to the same function, but I wouldn't expect that to cause any functional difference.

Comment: What's the easiest way to generate such a program and try it? Probably write a program to write it for you

Comment: It would fail the same way. It’s a common stack, and a function call creates a frame whether it is the same or a different function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RecursionError` is thrown when the call stack is exceeded. This most *commonly* occurs due to recursion, but it can occur in general.

To test this, we can write a quick `for` loop to generate a couple hundred different functions that call each other.

```
function = lambda: "Success!"
for _i in range(999):
    def new_function(f=function):
        f()
    function = new_function

print(function())
```

At 999, this fails with `RecursionError` (the one-thousandth function call is the `lambda`, not part of the for loop). Change that loop counter to 998 and it runs fine.

Comment: Even with just 99, I still don't see `Success!`...